# Can't access admin interface on server

Tags: api-platform.com

I'm trying to start a development of an api platform solution following the getting started documentation on the official site with docker.
When I'm on my local environnement there is no problem and I can access the admin with "https://localhost:444".
The problem is when I'm putting the app on a server I can't access this interface and I have this screen :
[image]

and this error messages in the console :
[image]

There is the content of my nelmio_cors.yaml :

`nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Preload', 'Fields']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': null`

I haven't found anything helpful to solve this problem after some hours of research...

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the same issue than this one: https://github.com/api-platform/admin/issues/262

What do you have when you inspect network activity (look at the github issue to see an example)? If you see that you're sending a request on http://localhost:444/api/docs.jsonld it should be a HTTPS/HTTP issue.

A solution, but not a perfect one as said on Github, would be to add TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,REMOTE_ADDR in your .env file.

Comment: I tried the solution of adding ",REMOTE_ADDR" to the .env file and it change nothing...

Comment: What error message do you see on console when trying to connect to admin in prod env?

Comment: I just add a screenshot of the error messages to my original post.

Comment: According to the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" you must have some restrictions in your nelmio_cors.yaml file, can you copy/paste the configuration you have?

Comment: I add it to my post.

Comment: In your .env file, replace your CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN with ^.*$. You will have to change it on prod but it should work normally